# Boost Asio callback doesn't get called

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm using Boost.Asio for network operations, they have to (and actually, can, there's no complex data structures or anything) remain pretty low level since I can't afford the luxury of serialization overhead (and the libs I found that did offer well enough performance seemed to be badly suited for my case).

The problem is with an async write I'm doing from the client (in QT, but that should probably be irrelevant here). The callback specified in the `async_write` doesn't get called, ever, and I'm at a complete loss as to why. The code is:

```
void SpikingMatrixClient::addMatrix() {
    std::cout << "entered add matrix" << std::endl;
    int action = protocol::Actions::AddMatrix;
    int matrixSize = this->ui->editNetworkSize->text().toInt();
    std::ostream out(&buf);
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&action), sizeof(action));
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&matrixSize), sizeof(matrixSize));
    boost::asio::async_write(*connection.socket(), buf.data(),
                             boost::bind(&SpikingMatrixClient::onAddMatrix, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

which calls the first write. The callback is

```
void SpikingMatrixClient::onAddMatrix(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
    std::cout << "entered onAddMatrix" << std::endl;
    if (!error) {
        buf.consume(bytes_transferred);
        requestMatrixList();
    } else {
        QString message = QString::fromStdString(error.message());
        this->ui->statusBar->showMessage(message, 15000);
    }
}
```

The callback never gets called, even though the server receives all the data. Can anyone think of any reason why it might be doing that?

P.S. There was a wrapper for that connection, and yes there will probably be one again. Ditched it a day or two ago because I couldn't find the problem with this callback.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but just in case... You are calling "run" on io_server somewhere to dispatch the callbacks?

Comment: Agreed.  There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code posted.  Would need to see more to diagnose.

Comment: @JohnB not a stupid question at all. As @Chad pointed out, there's nothing wrong with the limited code snippet posted. @TC1 I suggest boiling this problem down to a reproducible example, complete with `main` and `io_service.run()` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks guys, there was a call to `run()`, but apparently it runs out of work somewhere in between, so I guess a redesign is in order...

Comment: @TC1 please post an answer to your own question if you have solved it.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.stopping_the_io_service_from_running_out_of_work

Comment: @JohnB Thanks, I already read that when I first started using Asio, and that's how I fixed it, at least for now anyway.

Comment: @Sam Miller Will do once I get home & have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, posting a solution I found to be the most suitable (at least for now).

The client application is [being] written in QT, and I need the IO to be async. For the most part, the client receives calculation data from the server application and has to render various graphical representations of them.

Now, there's some key aspects to consider:

1. The GUI has to be responsive, it should not be blocked by the IO.
2. The client can be connected / disconnected.
3. The traffic is pretty intense, data gets sent / refreshed to the client every few secs and it has to remain responsive (as per item 1.).

As per the Boost.Asio documentation,

> Multiple threads may call io_service::run() to set up a pool of
>   threads from which completion handlers may be invoked. 
>   Note that all threads that have joined an io_service's pool are considered equivalent, and the io_service may distribute work across them in an arbitrary fashion.

Note that `io_service.run()` **blocks** until the io_service runs out of work.

With this in mind, the clear solution is to run `io_service.run()` from another thread. The relevant code snippets are

```
void SpikingMatrixClient::connect() {
    Ui::ConnectDialog ui;
    QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;
    ui.setupUi(dialog);
    if (dialog->exec()) {
        QString host = ui.lineEditHost->text();
        QString port = ui.lineEditPort->text();
        connection = TcpConnection::create(io);
        boost::system::error_code error = connection->connect(host, port);
        if (!error) {
            io = boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service>(new boost::asio::io_service);
            work = boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>(new boost::asio::io_service::work(*io));
            io_threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&SpikingMatrixClient::runIo, this, io));
        }
        QString message = QString::fromStdString(error.message());
        this->ui->statusBar->showMessage(message, 15000);
    }
}
```

for connecting & starting IO, where:

- `work` is a private `boost::shared_ptr` to the `boost::asio::io_service::work` object it was passed,
- `io` is a private `boost::shared_ptr` to a `boost::asio::io_service`,
- `connection` is a `boost::shared_ptr` to my connection wrapper class, and the `connect()` call uses a resolver etc. to connect the socket, there's plenty examples of that around
- and `io_threads` is a private `boost::thread_group`.

Surely it could be shortened with some typedefs if needed.

`TcpConnection` is my own connection wrapper implementation, which sortof lacks functionality for now, and I suppose I could move the whole thread thing into it when it gets reinstated. This snippet should be enough to get the idea anyway...

The disconnecting part goes like this:

```
void SpikingMatrixClient::disconnect() {
    work.reset();
    io_threads.join_all();
    boost::system::error_code error = connection->disconnect();
    if (!error) {
        connection.reset();
    }
    QString message = QString::fromStdString(error.message());
    this->ui->statusBar->showMessage(message, 15000);
}
```

- the work object is destroyed, so that the `io_service` can run out of work eventually,
- the threads are joined, meaning that all work gets finished before disconnecting, thus data shouldn't get corrupted,
- the `disconnect()` calls `shutdown()` and `close()` on the socket behind the scenes, and if there's no error, destroys the connection pointer.

Note, that there's no error handling in case of an error while disconnecting in this snippet, but it could very well be done, either by checking the error code (which seems more C-like), or throwing from the `disconnect()` if the error code within it represents an error after trying to disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem (callbacks not fired) but the circumstances are different from this question (`io_service` had jobs but still would not fire the handlers ). I will post this anyway and maybe it will help someone.

In my program, I set up an `async_connect()` then followed by `io_service.run()`, which blocks as expected.

`async_connect()` goes to `on_connect_handler()` as expected, which in turn fires `async_write()`.

`on_write_complete_handler()` does not fire, even though the other end of the connection has received all the data and has even sent back a response.

I discovered that it is caused by me placing program logic in `on_connect_handler()`. Specifically, after the connection was established and after I called `async_write()`, I entered an infinite loop to perform arbitrary logic, not allowing `on_connect_handler()` to exit. I assume this causes the `io_service` to not be able to execute other handlers, even if their conditions are met because it is stuck here. ( I had many misconceptions, and thought that `io_service` would automagically spawn threads for each `async_x()` call )

Hope that helps.